# What is the best way (algorithm) to find most weighted path in a weighted graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a simple graph like this:

```
(v1)---(v2)---(v3)---(v10)
 |      |      | 
(v4)---(v5)---(v6)
 |      |      | 
(v7)---(v8)---(v9)
```

I convert the game board into grids and each grid is a vertex and each vertex has a weight.
Now I need an algorithm to find most weighted way between one vertex which can be one of vertices **from (v1) to (v9)** and another vertex is **(v10)**.

**Example for vertices weight:** Consider that each vertex weight is 1, so, If my path be **(v1)->(v2)->(v3)->(v10)**, my path weight will be 4.

I already used BFS algorithm to find all possible paths, then calculate weights of proper paths (those paths which end with **(v10)**) between all paths. But BFS can't find all possible paths for me (maybe BF. However, I can use a trick for that, but I wonder if there is an algorithm for making my job easy and more efficient :).

Comment: In your example, what answer are you looking for?  Do you want the longest possible path, so something like `(v7)->(v8)->(v9)->(v6)->(v5)->(v4)->(v1)->(v2)->(v3)->(v10)`?    Or a shortest path from the farthest point.  So `(v7)->(v8)->(v5)->(v2)->(v3)->(v10)`?

Comment: The latter is a straightforward dynamic programming problem.  The former is...hard.